# Is Gracenote compatible with Windows 10 and Universal Windows Platform UWP/UAP?

Tags: gracenote

Is Gracenote compatible with Windows 10 and Universal Windows Platform (UWP/UAP) ?

We were trying to install de Nuget Package from:

http://www.nuget.org/packages/ParkSquare.Gracenote/

and when we tried to install it, the Visual Studio 2015 throws in the output window:

```
===================================================
Restoring packages for 'MyApp.UWP'.
Restoring packages for C:\src\dev\MyApp.UWP\project.json...
Installing ParkSquare.Gracenote 1.3.0.
ParkSquare.Gracenote 1.3.0 is not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0.
Some packages are not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0.
ParkSquare.Gracenote 1.3.0 is not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-arm).
Some packages are not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-arm).
ParkSquare.Gracenote 1.3.0 is not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-arm-aot).
Some packages are not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-arm-aot).
ParkSquare.Gracenote 1.3.0 is not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x86).
Some packages are not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x86).
ParkSquare.Gracenote 1.3.0 is not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x86-aot).
Some packages are not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x86-aot).
ParkSquare.Gracenote 1.3.0 is not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x64).
Some packages are not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x64).
ParkSquare.Gracenote 1.3.0 is not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x64-aot).
Some packages are not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x64-aot).
Package restore failed for 'MyApp.UWP'.
Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'MyApp.UWP'.
========== Finished ==========
```

At first sight we think that Gracenote is not compatible with Windows 10.

We're trying to include Gracenote in our app on Windows 10; in case it is possible, which APIs should we use?

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the package compatible with UWP, you need to a) contact package's developer to update the package or b) fork the package and convert/build it for UWP.

You can also implement the REST API of Gracenote yourself.